# Arduino compatible H bridge behaving unexpectedly

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, h-bridge

I have built an h bridge in a circuit simulator for controlling my brushed DC motor such that it can work with 5v supply from Arduino Uno here is its link to play around with the circuit [Circuit Simulation link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKIAsBmET2YKYFowwAoAE3BRRACYrKwLwA2SakEnAMwEMBXAGwAupcpTRpGI6rVbtu-IQJCNRkSgE4JaVcggsWYOG069BRRWgRUQW0VRY2d4aAHZnjC4wAcaNSjhUESAR8MCQwFzcPb19-QOCCMMNZEwUlOjUrDXAM5AJkRmgEN0hnLTBfBDVnKmcQqwMWZPkza0tsqzQ7dtzdJULi0shylErq2oJ6pONmshqrGko5phYrJtNZ6utxak2FmWnTACdwNylFvzOdOCIAdxAssFOH5ihb%204kwF-o6F8g3zv0pwBy1ed2BnxWmwhoPe1i6WTEEj%20dwR22%20WyRbyWiLh9m2yNxGMJwL%20AHNqJ5PNYvBSqWhPJQ9FjNji7HT8W90azIOzMQAlag8kFs8BgKx6VAsNTIPSFTkMaEi6EEpaKoXKojHFDKS4WebSFbwTUgPAoKl7HV7Q3XMFtcodNpWogChBi2mYF5USkyyWYH0wBBvLIi4MGoMSWhSiNhlHRugMJ1groi4GJwmR9MxzOLXZh8l4YPeibm71Mu46%201pS4Ex5xyRpjN7JZp03m6St2EEjvBi5ZFW9iMXNPayieFgj6tvCdjk4SGc1057WsgefG%20zaHUOfRG4566zaPzrxngI0AZxNhapK1L4BA3D4p5wRHPBc0%20KJ%20jvXAfT7uR%20QXpXm8-54pidyHvulAQTiBLQQehiAa854QYhrrzDeED3o%20z6SqBmBujBt5YU%205JoUSCAMIRfwCq%20RIEJR77jiwSASgG4bUBceCWhcXbcSwXGUDqvGCVBM5CVOYmiSsCBgagM4BBIKEyTCSmKQhpbsRml4wqmFyphpSYrBcKA9mWqCmeZilAeBWRmiaM52V2DlUng8nKU50lItQ7nAd5XmIX854pjSiHiFeRHfthdwptswVAQAHiaLxaBIeBoM4%207SosLAAMrEIlFBIBYUE0hYGXZSAOUoEQBWUZAimMBlWhZYKlVUDVJqVK0SBpZoCBUhVOVoB1VAWNYngZQEdJqOOrU5YGQA)
[image: H Bridge]
Now to start the motor I need to first turn on S5, S1 and S2 and then turn off S2 and S1 really fast (to not damage Arduino) , when I turn off S2 THEN S1 (and keep S5 on) current starts to flow through load (cool ,nothing unexpected happening) but if I first turn off S1 THEN S2 (and keep S5 on) current starts to flow through ALL transistors (try doing it in simulation), why is that happening ,why while turning off S1 and S2 sequence matters

### Second Problem

When I decrease the load to 10 ohms current starts to flow through all transistors why is that happening and can I fix it

Comment: 1) You mention S1 - S5 but they're not in the schematic. There are switches but they do not have a designator. 2) you made a complex design that relies on it's own state to switch transistors on/off. It has a several loops that act like a memory. This circuit is fine for educational purposes in a simulator. But you would not want to build this circuit with real components as it is almost guaranteed that something will break due to shorting the supply for example. Have a look at some common H-bridge circuits to learn how it is done.

Comment: yes, use standard H-bridge circuit, they are way simpler than your design, you can even find IC to drive your H-bridge Transistors and there is a lot of info on that available online. Moreover, it is not so common to design it using BJT. instead use MOSFET as they dissipate less energy and are easier to drive in case of power application.

Comment: Try replacing the left and right switch pairs with a voltage source and remove the switch in the middle (S5). You don't want to leave all of that floating when all the switches are open. You also don't want to allow both inputs to be high at the same time.

Comment: You also need to remove the lines that connect the NPN collectors to 5V. Then the circuit will work.

Comment: Second problem is the large base resistors not allowing the transistors to reach saturation causes a large CE voltage drop. Try 560 ohm.

Comment: You should put labels in your diagram instead of explaining them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your circuit, the 2K resistors keep all the transistor on.

Since both the top and bottom transistors turn on at about the same level, they basically try to short the 9V to GND, causing around 188mA to flow, and heating the transistors with around 1W.

The fundamental design of this circuit is really flawed, as it also lets current flow into the arduino if it drives the lines with 5V

The way to solve this is by removing the positive feedback loop from the circuit

Instead of wiring the transistors to the middle of the H-bridge, we need to wire them away from those points. We can grab 2 extra NPN transistors, and use them to switch opposite pairs of top and bottom transistors for both directions.

This would look like:

[image: Electric circuit diagram showing an H bridge make of discrete transistors, being controlled pair wise with an extra NPN transistor. The circuit also includes a safety to prevent both sides from being turned at once]

[Schematic](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5AWAnC1b0DYRNpMB2MAZmLgFYAmMADgjMhDMYbIFMBaMMAKABcR8GaiCJEs%20MSMkNOUaGAxlqFBJHoINSBRpDsYFStTL4qZZMXzLwcEABNWAMwCGAVwA2vPiGpEKUrNQYCP5QuhAwCkoqiPhIVIT4uvqGxlTUeAhkSOTWDPbO7p623khYRJQlZRQMfvmuHtzF%20IgiFc3BvjV2jvWeAO7eQSLVlcMMkNwD1KWtfoEdFRMDElUM7WNQkwIt5X4rs5vLkp0CkgZYS6dY5942N5fpNWQBQ-db8yA3HyeX%207tXIFU43eQ3%20HyBh28vhCgmEYmEvyEIR8fnhkJRIiRcThSMROOEGBMmIRIOCEPBCBJRywEP2GhJxXB6UGZMpn26BQaTUklLWPLZtR6hS82MBQ2mNKGDAg7Go0F8SGQkCQRFoZFE%20ESyRoFE1SCyYEgJCwhryQoa-EJfgQQ3WNuC0t0coVSpVapMWugBh1eqykCCRGQTFNHN67xm9JZgLZDwjzKZwOp0eEdpjWztzLpzImCDATDpNnBNnGuDgFHQFbQiUNcj8yTk8Auper6KGvKjZgd6Z5mcknch%2037j0YOgeNiHQ37EwA5rcWDph89xpt%20KUGJHRZHHbLoPgEIQEBRCYEss9gnovWQfc090bCFfcqHhZbVMmQFa39u5XuD0fBMQMEDPwL29ZRNUgCQUGUMxHzqYUACd3yJNEPwQaFpXgbhENFNFN3Q3IJmwjB1zZU1hC3AjCPfV9Iyya0Y0o7gAGVrGeN8uBaCiIGcNwAGdWFCChmJHVlyIjBiGB4-jBO4WcOLJIZ5MBbNNlnZBJTJONlwmAAlQEI2hdTAWLUJXyYbToDIbg9KUtC-Fskz1xYUISysvThy%20O4VBc4zsB8mArIGftaLiT8tkNNjIzIsKgtCkLrRmS4gnXGZN0SrDGDimZkv0i5GNXCgxKwNdctCGU5SMf0sgwQChFEMQOHI%20V-TiFZ0jAQrFQ4PNYPNfpsGIt8SvbGcBpYDqxsYQqXO4AAPAa-CvYN-ToGhAXAPwmKcBxWF4ABPAAdXjeHgpwADteIAS2OgB7eDuBuz5hAREBZqcQ0CEYORwnZcynpEWtNiAA)

Note that by the nature of BJT transistors, it should only be used to drive low power DC motors, else the transistor get hot quickly

Comment: *Note that by the nature of BJT transistors, it should only be used to drive low power DC motors, else the transistor get hot quickly* When using low power transistors, that is true. However, high power transistors do exist that are capable of switching very high currents. These also get hot so they come in packages that can be mounted on a heatsink. For entertainment, see some examples here: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/how-powerful-can-a-transistor-be/

Comment: @bimpelrekkie I have some triple transistor Darlington's (Trilingtons? :-)) that were used in a large UPS for a bank mainframe. Each is a decent handful. I'll have to check the specs.